# Уменьшить массив объектов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, производительность

У меня есть массив объектов:

```
[
  {date: 'Mon', count: 5, ids: '3,7'},
  {date: 'Mon', count: 1, ids: '2'},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4, ids: '16,23'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '0,1'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '8,9'},
]
```

Я хочу сложить count для одинаковых дат и снова получить массив объектов.
Ожидаемый результат:

```
[
  {date: 'Mon', count: 6},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 4},
]
```

Каким наилучшим способом можно это сделать?

Comment: Вам просто код написать?

Comment: Я новичок в js. Хотя бы совет, что использовать

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Как внутри reduce сравнивать поля у объектов?

Comment: @ybw2431 а зачем вы написали заголовок и описание вопроса на английском? Тут можно писать на русском (и нужно)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {date: 'Mon', count: 5, ids: '3,7'},
  {date: 'Mon', count: 1, ids: '2'},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4, ids: '16,23'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '0,1'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '8,9'},
];

const r1 = data.reduce((r,i) => (r[i.date] = (r[i.date] || (r[i.date] = 0)) + i.count, r), {});
const r2 = Object.entries(r1).map(i => ({date: i[0], count: i[1]}));

console.log(r2);
```