# Сложение объектов в массиве если есть одинаковые значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Необходимо сложить значения где одинаковые имена

```
const arr = [
  {'ключ1': 'Антон', 'ключ2': '100'},
  {'ключ1': 'Андрей', 'ключ2': '200'},
  {'ключ1': 'Сергей', 'ключ2': '300'},
  {'ключ1': 'Антон', 'ключ2': '400'}
]
```

Желаемый результат

```
const arr = [
  {'ключ1': 'Антон', 'ключ2': '500'},
  {'ключ1': 'Андрей', 'ключ2': '200'},
  {'ключ1': 'Сергей', 'ключ2': '300'},
]
```

Comment: дубль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270321/

Comment: благодарю. Сам не нашёл

Comment: @entithat Зачем указывать вопрос для закрытия текущего как дубликат, если на нём -4 и ни одного плюса?

Comment: @0xdb, потому что там есть ответ для этого вопроса.